# How to handle error datatypes and response messages in RESTful API design

Tags: rest, error-handling, api-design, raml

I am building my first RESTful API for practising and learning. I am using RAML and will realize it with MuleSofts AnypointStudio. I don't really know how to deal with responses, particularly, error responses. I managed to figure out which HTTP status codes I want for my responses but didn't manage to figure out how to handle the response messages.

Do I need to define response datatype and example message for every response code (200, 201, 204, 404 etc.)? If I can have one datatype and one example message, how do I do use them accordingly?

Currently, I have defined one error type and one example message.

Error.raml

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType
type: object
description: This general error structure is used throughout this API.
properties:
  code:
    type: integer
    minimum: 400
    maximum: 599
  description?:
    type: string
    default: "Bad query parameter [$size]: Invalid integer value [abc]"
    example: The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it
  reasonPhrase?:
    type: string
    examples:
      example: Bad Request
      example1: Forbidden
example: !include ../examples/error_example.json
```

error_example.json

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "description": "Bad query parameter [$size]: Invalid integer value [abc]",
  "reasonPhrase": "Bad Request"
}
```

As you can see, I have variables in both datatype and example message. They were generated by Restlet. I don't know how to utilise them yet so I just left them for the time being.

Would really appreciate any help and tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to define response datatype and example message for every response code (200, 201, 204, 404 etc.)? If I can have one datatype and one example message, how do I do use them accordingly?

No you don't. For a resource you could specify responses such as `200` or `404` (these are the most commonly used)

From the docs:

```
resourceTypes:
  collection:
    description: Collection of available songs in Jukebox
    get:
      description: Get a list of songs based on the song title.
      responses:
        200:
          body:
            application/json:
    post:
      description: |
        Add a new song to Jukebox.
      queryParameters:
        access_token:
          description: "The access token provided by the authentication application"
          example: AABBCCDD 
          required: true
          type: string
      body:
        application/json:
          type: song
      responses:
        200:
          body:
            application/json:
              example: |
                { "message": "The song has been properly entered" }
```

An example of a resource with a not found error:

```
collection-item:
  description: Entity representing a <<resourcePathName|!singularize>>
  get:
    description: |
      Get the <<resourcePathName|!singularize>>
      with <<resourcePathName|!singularize>>Id =
      {<<resourcePathName|!singularize>>Id}
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
      404:
        body:
          application/json:
            example: |
              {"message": "<<resourcePathName|!singularize>> not found" }
```

There's an excellent [blog post](https://blog.restcase.com/rest-api-error-codes-101/) about this. Have a look at [RAML tutorials](https://raml.org/developers/raml-200-tutorial#use-case) as they have nice docs.
You could also have a look at [Swagger](https://swagger.io/tools/swaggerhub/faster-api-design/) for more "inspiration".

Comment: This is sort of what I was looking for. I was hoping there is a way to create one DataType or Schema (with variables?) for error messages and re-use it accordingly for every error response. But this will have to do, thank you

Comment: I want to wait for more answers if it's okay. I will mark it as an answered in a few days if there won't be any more answers